# Maximum element in a region

Tags: c++

I want to compare the value of an element in an array with the neighboring elements (3x3) and find the maximum (figure). My code below doesn't seem to work. Which part has gone wrong?
[image]

```
int data[10][10] = {};
int dataMax[10][10] = {};
int r_size = 3;  // Size of region to compare
int h = floor(r_size/2);    

for(int i = h; i < ( 10 - h  ) ; i++){       
    for(int j = h; j < ( 10 - h ); j++){
      int max = 0;

        for( int ii = i - h; ii < ( i + h ); ii++ ){
            for( int jj = j - h; jj < ( j + h  ); jj++ ){

               if( data[ii][jj] > max ){

                 max = data[ii][jj];

               }else{

                  dataMax[ii][jj] = 0;

                }
            }
        }

   dataMax[ii][jj]  = data[ii][jj];

    }
}
```

**[Edited based on the answer]**

```
int data[10][10] = 
{{0,0,3,0,1,0,0,0,0,1},
{0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0},
{0,4,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,8,1,1,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,3,6,0,0,2,0},
{2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};

int dataMax[10][10] = {};
int r_size = 3;  // Size of region to compare
int h = floor(r_size/2.0);    

for(int i = h; i < ( 10 - h  ) ; i++){        //**** correction ****
   for(int j = h; j < ( 10 - h ); j++){      //**** correction ****
     int max = 0;
     int max_x = 0;              //**** correction ****
     int max_y = 0;

    for( int ii = i - h; ii <= ( i + h ); ii++ ){         //**** correction ****     
        for( int jj = j - h; jj <= ( j + h  ); jj++ ){    //**** correction ****

           if( data[ii][jj] > max ){

             max = data[ii][jj];
             max_x = ii;              //**** correction ****
             max_y = jj;

           }else{

   //           dataMax[ii][jj] = 0;

            }
        }
    }

   dataMax[max_x][max_y]  = max;       //**** correction ****

   }
}
```

I expect to get following dataMax:
[image]

Comment: Found another bug, edited my answer (marked it with edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following may help: (https://ideone.com/xJXzp8)

```
int getMax(int minx, int maxx, int miny, int maxy)
{
    minx = std::max(minx, 0);
    maxx = std::min(maxx, 10);
    miny = std::max(miny, 0);
    maxy = std::min(maxy, 10);
    int res = data[minx][miny];

    for (int x = minx; x != maxx; ++x) {
        for (int y = miny; y != maxy; ++y) {
            res = std::max(res, data[x][y]);
        }
    }
    return res;
}

void compute()
{
    const int h = 3;  // Size of region to compare

    for (int x = 0; x != 10; ++x) {
        for (int y = 0; y != 10; ++y) {
            dataMax[x][y] = getMax(x - h / 2, x + h - h / 2,
                                   y - h / 2, y + h - h / 2);
        }
    }
}

void filter()
{
    for (int x = 0; x != 10; ++x) {
        for (int y = 0; y != 10; ++y) {
            if (dataMax[x][y] != data[x][y]) {
                dataMax[x][y] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @boogiedoll: I hope now it is was you want.

Comment: what does these error mean?
error C2530: 'a_i' : references must be initialized
error C3531: 'a_i': a symbol whose type contains 'auto' must have an initializer

Comment: I still couldn't get the correct output (see above) from your code.

Comment: i really appreciate your effort providing a code. do you have any idea how your code can produce the intended result as shown above?

Comment: @boogiedoll: I use C++11 in the printing function (you may use regular loop instead). (https://ideone.com/xJXzp8) should do what you want now.

Answer (score 1):

well, one thing is this:

```
int h = floor(r_size/2);
```

h is now 1.

and:

```
    for( int ii = i - h; ii < ( i + h ); ii++ ){
```

iterates between `i-1` to `i+1` for a total of two iterations. You should change that to `<=` for three iterations.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, where you write

```
dataMax[ii][jj]  = data[ii][jj];
```

the variables `ii` as well as `jj` aren't declared anymore. Further: You are not storing the `max` value anywhere, which should happen, if you are looking for it.

**EDIT:** Found another mistake in your edit: try setting `dataMax[max_x][max_y]  = max;` because you messed up rows and columns `data[max_x][max_y]` should have been `data[max_y][max_x]` as far as I can see.

But anyways, since you are storing the max, why not use it?

Comment: @boogiedoll Then you will have to tell us, what is going wrong?!